# Ordering a Column with text and numbers in numerical order

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Below is two columns representing a 62 min time period broken down into minute by minute segments. I am having problems getting the segment name column to go in order ie ES-L FTD 1, ES-L FTD 2, ES-L FTD 3... I need them to be in order to produce minute by minute graph displaying the output data.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
Segment Name    Time       Output Data
ES-L FTD 1       1:00
ES-L FTD 10      1:00
ES-L FTD 11      1:00
ES-L FTD 12      1:00
ES-L FTD 13      1:00
ES-L FTD 14      1:00
ES-L FTD 15      1:00
ES-L FTD 16      1:00
ES-L FTD 17      1:00
ES-L FTD 18      1:00
ES-L FTD 19      1:00
ES-L FTD 2       1:00
ES-L FTD 20      1:00
ES-L FTD 21      1:00
ES-L FTD 22      1:00
ES-L FTD 23      1:00
ES-L FTD 24      1:00
ES-L FTD 25      1:00
ES-L FTD 26      1:00
ES-L FTD 27      1:00
ES-L FTD 28      1:00
ES-L FTD 29      1:00
ES-L FTD 3       1:00
ES-L FTD 30      1:00
ES-L FTD 31      1:00
ES-L FTD 32      1:00
ES-L FTD 33      1:00
ES-L FTD 34      1:00
ES-L FTD 35      1:00
ES-L FTD 36      1:00
ES-L FTD 37      1:00
ES-L FTD 38      1:00
ES-L FTD 39      1:00
ES-L FTD 4       1:00
ES-L FTD 40      1:00
ES-L FTD 41      1:00
ES-L FTD 42      1:00
ES-L FTD 43      1:00
ES-L FTD 44      1:00
ES-L FTD 45      1:00
ES-L FTD 46      1:00
ES-L FTD 47      1:00
ES-L FTD 48      1:00
ES-L FTD 49      1:00
ES-L FTD 5       1:00
ES-L FTD 50      1:00
ES-L FTD 51      1:00
ES-L FTD 52      1:00
ES-L FTD 53      1:00
ES-L FTD 54      1:00
ES-L FTD 55      1:00
ES-L FTD 56      1:00
ES-L FTD 57      1:00
ES-L FTD 58      1:00
ES-L FTD 59      1:00
ES-L FTD 6       1:00
ES-L FTD 60      1:00
ES-L FTD 61      1:00
ES-L FTD 62      1:00
ES-L FTD 7       1:00
ES-L FTD 8       1:00
ES-L FTD 9       1:00
```

Comment: The answer will not change by asking again, you will need to either use helper columns, one for the text and another for the number and sort on those, or change the string to use the same number of digits for the numbers ie, `ES-L FTD 01`

Comment: I didn't feel my previous question was worded properly / got my point across so wasn't sure if there was another way. How would i add a digit to the string?

Comment: You will need to parse the string.  But the best solution is to change the data at the source to bring in the number as two or three digits.

Comment: Unfortunately its a raw data output so i can't change at the source

Comment: Have you got any idea what the formula would look like for that?

Comment: is your ES-L FTD constant throughout your data set ?

Comment: Yeah it will always be ES-L FTD followed by number representing minute in sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend setting an index (desired order) for your segment name.

Officially, you can find Microsoft's solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column

But, I think the following is more helpful: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/SORT-Order/td-p/370139

Thanks!
William